# How to populate the EditText data while on resuming the state?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

Here is the following scenario:

1. Filling the `EditText` and other `Fields` in Activity `A`
2. Moving from Activity `A` to Activity `B` on `Button`click
3. Now Moving from Activity `B` to Activity `A` on Button Click
4. populated `EditText` is gone now.  They are all empty
5. These fields should be pre-populated (as user has already filled them)

Is there any way to save the current state of Activity `A`. So that I can populated the `EditText` back? If not then How can I achieve the above task?

Comment: Do you have assigned unique IDs to the EditTexts? As in `android:id="@+id/foobar"`? If so, the Activity should save their state..

Comment: "Now Moving from Activity B to Activity A on Button Click" - you can just call finish() from B. The state will be automatically saved if you have ids for the EditText in your xml.

Comment: @Floern @Shadab I assigned unique `ID` for each text view. Here is the scenario:
User filled the mandatory fields in Activity A through UI and move to activity b using ActivityB_.intent(Activity1.this).start(); code. Now User coming back to Activity A using ActivityA_.intent(ActivityB.this).start(); code. UI of Activity is blank now (Data which I filled is not there now:)

Comment: Ah, I thought you go back to the previous instance of A, not 'forward' to a new one. In that case you have to save the data manually, like mentioned below with shared preferences or alike.

Comment: Got it and populate the edit text with the same data again. right?

Answer (score 1):

Use SharedPreferences.Editor to save the EditText data onPause, and retrieve the data with SharedPreferences onResume. That's the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

How are you moving from b back to a? If youre using an intent then your starting a new instance of that 'a' activity. Like some one mentioned above you should be using finish in your b activity which would take you back to a. If you need to populate a with data from b then you should use startActivityForResult - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

To save the activity state, override OnSaveInstanceState() method.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putString("key", somevalue); //save your data in key-value pair
}
```

and restore the value using,

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    somevalue = savedInstanceState.getString("key"); 
}
```

Use this method if you are destroying the activity and creating it again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you misunderstood my question. User filled the mandatory fields in `Activity A` through UI and move to `activity b` using `ActivityB_.intent(Activity1.this).start();` code. Now User coming back to `Activity A` using `ActivityA_.intent(ActivityB.this).start();` code. UI of Activity is blank now (Data which I filled is not there now:)

Comment: I got that you are creating a new instance of Activity A but you are not deleting the previous one is it? You can use this answer if you are otherwise go with shared preference.